# Simple hello-world app on load of 800 concurrent requests is slow (130+ms)

Tags: node.js, performance, response-time

Iv'e installed on my local machine a simple NodeJS Server (v8.16.2) with the following hello-world code snippet:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 4000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world!');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

I'm load testing the server using 800 parallel requests via JMeter and getting an average response time of 130(+)ms.

Any ideas what tweaks \ configurations I might require in order to achieve a better average response time?

Comment: With respect, a 130ms response from a non-load-balanced non-clustered naive node app running on your localhost with 800 concurrent connections **is not slow, it's fast**. Especially if the same machine runs the jmeter load. To help you make this faster, we need to know a lot more than you've told us about your setup (machine, OS, versions of things, local network.)

Answer (score 2):

A single instance of Node.js runs in a single thread. To take advantage of multi-core systems, the user will sometimes want to launch a cluster of Node.js processes to handle the load.

The [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module allows easy creation of child processes that all share server ports.

[HTTP/2](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html) commonly called SPDY is the latest web protocol standard developed by the IETF HTTP workgroup. HTTP/2 makes web browsing faster, easier and lower bandwidth usage. It focuses on performance, especially to solve problems that still occur in previous versions of HTTP/1.x. Currently, you can see some popular web like google, facebook and youtube, have implemented the HTTP/2 protocol on its web page. comment it in your code.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
//const http2 = require('http2');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

/*const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
 };*/

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  // const server = http2.createSecureServer(options);
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(4000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

and using the newest version of node js.